# Switching Value and Header in an Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say that I want to enter employee names as values into an excel table of date (first column) vs rostered shift (header).

I'd like to be able to autofill a table on another sheet, with date (column) and employee (header), and now the shift as a value.

See linked image for more explanation.

I've tried various combinations of Index, VLookup, Match and Column. In particular, I'm struggling with identifying a row in Table 1 by the "row header" ie the date.

Is there a way to do this within Excel? A way that keeps it to a table structured reference?

Edit:

I think that I managed to figure it out:

[Roster_Sample Conversion Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBlWB.png)

With the cells under the employee's names using:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX((Roster_Sample[#Headers]),
               MATCH(Roster_Sample[[#Headers],[Alf]],(Roster_Sample[@[Date]:[_]]),0)),"")
```

Any further advice or improvements appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to use the formulas that will get your result. To help us help you, please add a screenshot of your data and the formulas you tried. Otherwise, it sounds like if you restructured your data, then you could create 2 pivot tables to display your two views...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- If necessary, Copy Dates from Sheet 1 to sheet 2.
- Formula in cell `AB41` in `Sheet 2`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$W$40:$Y$40,MATCH(AB$40,Sheet1!$W41:$Y41,0)),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- Fill formula across.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.